# Profiling for cells instead of functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, profiler

I have a function that in turn calls many more functions. I want to use the profiler to identify what parts of the code is most time demanding.

Is it possible to get the profile summary **sorted by cells**, instead of function calls?

For instance, is it possible to get the profiler to output this:

```
  Cells    Calls   Total time ...  
  Part 1       1         .... ...
  Part 2       1         .... ...
```

instead of:

```
  Function name   Calls   Total time ...  
  func1               1         .... ...
  func2               1         .... ...
```

For the following code:

```
%% Part 1:
a = 1;
b = 2;
X = func1(a,b);

%% Part 2:
c = a+b;
Y = func2(c,b);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always extract the profiling information for each cell like so:

```
%% Part 1
profile on
%// Some code...
profile off
S1 = profile('info');

%% Part 2
profile on
%// Some more code...
profile off
S2 = profile('info');
```

The structures `S1` and `S2` should hold the profiling information for each cell. Remember to put `profile on` and `profile off` at the beginning and the end of each code cell to reset the profiling information.

To view the profile information in HTML form, you can use `profview`. For example:

```
profview(0, S1)
```

The first argument is an index in the `FunctionTable` field of the profile information struct, that corresponds to the function you want to display in the profile viewer.

Comment: Now I can display S1 and S2 in the command window, but I don't get them in the profiler window. In fact, now everything disappeared from that window. Do you know if there's a way I can get S1 and S2 to appear in the profiler? Thanks again =)

Comment: @RobertP. I think `profview` can help you. See my revised answer.